# Spring's PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer won't ignore unresolvable files

Tags: spring

I am using spring's PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer as follows :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:default.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/webextractor.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Despite having set the `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` property to `true`, I still get a `FileNotFoundException` on `/home/kaykay/webextractor.properties`. I know I could just create this file and leave it empty, but I'd like to know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` set to true will ignore placeholders that are not set and not throw an exception.
For example if you have  the following property in your class `@Value("${person.age}")` and no corresponding value set in your properties file.

The `ignoreResourceNotFound` property set to true will have the behavior you expected, that is ignore a resource that isn't found.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 10):

I have gone through your problem , I think Osiris is right about the property `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` . But in case of your , you should to set the property `ignoreResourceNotFound` true. So that , if the file is not existing then it will ignore that file.

Modified code will be

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:default.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/webextractor.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

try this code and let me know.